# if f and g are bounded, show that $f^2 - g^2$ is also bounded

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Question: if $f \space and \space g$ are two bounded functions, show that $f^2 - g^2$ is a bounded function.

My attempt:

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are bounded. Therefore, there exists $M$, $N > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \le M$ and $|g(x)| \le N$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Now, $|f(x)^2 - g(x)^2| = ||f(x)|^2 - |g(x)|^2| \le |M^2 - N^2|$

Therefore, $f^2 - g^2$ is bounded.

Is that correct?

EDIT: Solution I came up with (Sorry I'm a bot late).

$|f(x)^2 - g(x)^2| = |f(x)^2 + - g(x)^2| \le |f(x)^2| + |g(x)^2| \le M^2 + N^2$

Comment: No. What if $M=N$. For example, $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are both bounded by $1$, but it is false that $\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x$ is bounded by $1^2-1^2=0$.

Comment: So should I write M cannot equal to N?

Comment: Try the triangle inequality.
edit: It's your last step that is incorrect.

Comment: But isn't |f(x)|^2 <= M^2? Also, isn't triangle inequality only for addition?

Comment: Subtraction is a kind of addition, and you have $|\cdot\|$ to help you.

Comment: @kimichi lover I think I got you guys. Thanks!

Comment: @Manny:  you should write up the answer you have come to.  The FAQ encourages it.  Then, after a delay, you can accept it to show it is all you need.  I am glad we could be of help.  Writing up an answer is a good way to make sure you understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$|f| \leq M \implies |f |^2 \leq M^2$$

$$|g| \leq N \implies |g |^2 \leq N^2$$

$$|f^2 - g^2 | \leq |f|^2 + |g|^2 \leq M^2 + N^2$$

Hence it is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

If
$|f| \le M$
and
$|g| \le N$
then
$|f+g| \le M+N$
and
$|f-g| \le M+N$
so that
$|f^2-g^2|
=|(f+g)(f-g)|
\le (M+N)^2
$.

Answer (score 0):

One more:

$a^2-b^2 \le a^2+b^2;$  $a,b$ real.

$b^2-a^2\le a^2+b^2$.

$|f^2(x) -g^2(x)| \le (f^2(x) +g^2(x))$

$\le M^2 +N^2$,

where  $|f(x)| \le M, |g(x)| \le N$, with $M,N$ real.